# How to extract out the IP and IP range from the below text?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var client_content = "1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.34   4.4.4.4/5.5.5.55-67 please restart those machine";

var patt = /???/gm;

console.log(client_content.match(patt))
```

I want to match the pattern, then get the list `[1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.34, 4.4.4.4, 5.5.5.55-67]`, who can help with this?

I only know `/\d+(?:\.\d+){3}/gm` can match the IP, but can not match the range(`5.5.5.55-57`), its close to it.

Who can help with this?

Comment: Just add `(?:-\d+)?` to the end of your regex: `/\d+(?:\.\d+){3}(?:-\d+)?/gm`

Comment: @ctwheels Thanks, this works to me.

Comment: No sure why this question got a downvote. It may be elementary, but its purpose is clear and well worded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```js
var client_content = "1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.34    4.4.4.4/5.5.5.55-67 please restart those machine";

var patt = /(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(?:-\d{1,3})?/gm;

console.log(client_content.match(patt))
```